# how to remove the border-right for a last child in css

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the border-right for the last child using css. I'm using the html below:

```
 <div class="dividers">
     <div class="clone_container">
       <img src="clone.png"/>
        <a class="button-link">Clone</a>
     </div> 
    <div class="delete">
       <img src="delete.png"/>
        <a class="button-link">Delete</a>
     </div>
   <div class="abort">
       <img src="abort.png"/>
        <a class="button-link">Abort</a>
     </div> 
  <div class="pause">
       <img src="pause.png"/>
        <a class="button-link">Pause</a>
     </div>
 </div>     //end of dividers div
```

and the css:

```
div.dividers a {
display: inline-block;
border-right: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    border-radius: 4px;
   height: 22px;
}
div.dividers {
   margin-right: -3px;
   padding-right: 0px
   }

   div.dividers a:last-child { border-right: none;  }
```

when i do a `{ border-right: none;  }` like shown above, all the borders are removed. 
how can i fix this? anyone with any ideas??

The output i am looking for is:
Clone | Delete | Abort | Pause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
div.dividers > div:last-child > a { border-right: none;  }
```

Your code `div.dividers a:last-child` means

- Select all `<a>` such as

  - Are last child of its parent
  - Are descendants of a `<div>` with class `dividers`.

The code `div.dividers > div:last-child > a { border-right: none;  }` means

- Select all `<a>` such as

  - Are children of a div `<div>` which

    - Is the last child of its parent
    - Is a child of a `<div>` with class `dividers`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to target last div in `.dividers` div:

```
div.dividers div:last-child a { 
   border-right: none;  
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KX9XF/)